# Application of the Archimedean Property in Proving $1^* \subseteq \alpha\beta$ for Dedekind Cuts

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm working through a proof in the context of real numbers constructed via Dedekind cuts, specifically focusing on Step 6 of Theorem 1.19 from Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis." The goal is to demonstrate that the multiplication axioms of a field hold for these real numbers, particularly that the product of a Dedekind cut $\alpha$ and its inverse $\beta$ contains the unit cut $1*$, i.e., $1^* \subseteq \alpha\beta$.

The proof involves showing that every element $p$ of $1^*$ (where $1^*$ is the set of all rational numbers less than 1) is in the product $\alpha\beta$. The approach by Yesid Fonseca on Math StackExchange ([Step 6 Real construction from Rational Baby Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624254/step-6-real-construction-from-rational-baby-rudin/1634722#1634722)), which I am following, is as follows:

- It's clear that every $p \leq 0$ in $1^*$ is in $\alpha\beta$.
- For $0 < p < 1$, there's some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p < \frac{n}{n+2}$, and every $m \geq n$ satisfies $p < \frac{m}{m+2}$.

I am struggling to understand how the Archimedean property is applied to yield $p < \frac{n}{n+2}$. Rudin's version of the Archimedean property states that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > 0$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $nx > y$. I am unsure of the correct choice of $x$ and $y$ in this context and how to rigorously apply this property to arrive at the desired inequality.

The inverse set in this context is defined in the following way.
Let $ \beta^+ $ be the set $ \{p\in\mathbb{Q}:p>0$ and there's $r>0$ such that $\frac{1}{p}-r\notin\alpha\} $

Could someone provide a detailed explanation or guide me through the correct application of the Archimedean property in this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}p<\frac n{n+2}&\iff-p>-\frac n{n+2}\\&\iff1-p>1-\frac n{n+2}=\frac2{n+2}\\&\iff n+2>\frac2{1-p}\\&\iff n>\frac2{1-p}-2=\frac{2p}{1-p}.\end{align}By the Archimedean Property, such a natural $n$ exists.

Comment: Approved! +1...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.